# Username and Password not Matching Error Messages in Java

Tags: java, mysql

The below form , retrieves MySQL database username and password and check them with user's input.

Error messages on password or username incorrect is not showing. I tried many methods but not working as expected.

How can I code that functionality?

[image]

```
private void mysettingChangebtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

    String val1 = usernametxt.getText();
    String val2 = passwordtxt.getText();

    if( val1.equals("") || val2.equals("")){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill all fields and try again .... ");
           usernametxt.setText("");
           passwordtxt.setText("");


    }

    try{

        String sql1 = "SELECT username FROM logininfo WHERE username LIKE '"+val1+"'" ;
        String sql2 = "SELECT password FROM logininfo WHERE password LIKE '"+val2+"'" ;

        pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pst2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);


         rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
         rs2 = pst2.executeQuery();

        while(rs1.next()){
            String uname=rs1.getString("username");
            //System.out.println(uname);

        while(rs2.next()){
           String pwd=rs2.getString("password");
            //System.out.println(pwd);



         if(val1.equals(uname) && val2.equals(pwd)){

            chg2.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        } else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Information is Incorrect. Try Again.... ");
        }

        if(!(val1.equals(uname)) || !(val2.equals(pwd))){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Information is Incorrect. Try Again.... ");


                }
        }}




    }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "errrrrr"+e);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to look up the user by username AND password:

```
String username = usernametxt.getText();
String password = passwordtxt.getText();
// avoid SQL injection by setting query parameters with '?'
String sql = "SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, username);
st.setString(2, password );
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();    
if (!rs.next()) {
    // no records found, login  failed
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Information is Incorrect.");
}
else {
    // record found, login succeeded
    // assuming here that there is a unique constraint in the database
    // on (username, password), otherwise multiple records could be found
    chg2.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: It worked..I added error message to show null entries too .. Thanks for the help :) @Adriaan Koster

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using one query by passing 2 params

```
 "SELECT username FROM logininfo WHERE username  = '"+val1+"' 
  and password =  '"+val2+"' " ;
```

You need to take care of sql injection as well..Pass the parameters using preparedstatement and bind them to the query.

In your case

```
 while(rs1.next()){
        String uname=rs1.getString("username");
        //System.out.println(uname);
     }  // <-- close it...

      while(rs2.next()){
       String pwd=rs2.getString("password");
        //System.out.println(pwd);
    }  <--- close it..
```

remove the two `}}` at the end and try again...

Comment: It's better to set parameters on PreparedStatements using the "?" and setXXX() methods to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: I mentioned that in the answer..check please @AdriaanKoster

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. But why not show the correct way in your code as well?

Answer (score 1):

i have problem like that, i solved whe i removed md5 encrypt from security-file but maybe your DB use md5 encrypt and your app not try to look that

Answer (score 1):

Make user that `String val2 = passwordtxt.getText();` is not returning an encrypted value. Java password field might not be returning the plain text value.